# "Right way" to add attributes to all numbers in NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift

Is this a good way to add attributes to all numbers in an NSMutableAttributedString?

```
let reg: NSRegularExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\d+", options: nil, error: nil)!

reg.enumerateMatchesInString(str, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length)) {
    (result, _, _) -> Void in
        paragraph.addAttribute(attributeName, value: attributeValue, range: result.range)
}
```

Or maybe it should be done in other way? I'm totaly new to XCode (comming from "PHP world") so I just want to make sure I'm doing things in Swift as I should.

Comment: This is about as terse as it gets, and it is easy to read.

Comment: I guess you have some extension for `length` property that uses `countElements` for `String` as `length` is not built in in swift.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight!
"length" property is built into NSMutableAttributedString @Kirsteins  : `let paragraph: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Latviešu valoda")
println(paragraph.length)`